# How to change the value of the database table (Boolean Column which is set as default false) when button is clicked using JQuery or codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, database, codeigniter

Im using codeigniter datatable where i want to "disable" the specific row when i click delete button (data should not be erased from databse).

For that i have already set a column in database(column name: deleteflag datatype: boolean default value is false).

when i change that value from false to true in database, that particular id (tr row will be disabled) which im doing manually in database.

i have added a class called $delstatus in delete button and assigned an array ('0'=>' ', '1'=> 'disabled')

All i want is that when i click on delete button that id row should be disabled by changing boolean value from false to true.

```
Here is my  Controller:

    $active_info = array('0'=>'','1'=>'disabled');
          foreach ($list as $lists) 
          {
              $delstatus=$active_info[$lists->deleteflag];
              $row = array();
              $slno++;
              $row[] = '<input type="checkbox" class="'.$delstatus.' data-check" value="'.$lists->id.'" onclick="showBottomDelete()"/>';
              $row[] = $slno;
              $row[] = '<a class="btn '.$delstatus.' btn-sm btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Edit"  onclick="editCase('."'".$lists->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn '.$delstatus.' btn-sm btn-danger" id="btnDelete" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Delete"  onclick="deleteCase('."'".$lists->id."'".')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</a>';


Here is the  view for delete in ajax:

    function deleteCase(id)
    {
        if(confirm('Are you sure delete this data?'))
        {

            // ajax delete data to database
            $.ajax({
                url : "<?php echo site_url('case/ajax_delete')?>/"+id,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {
                    //if success reload ajax table
                    $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                        reloadTable();

                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error deleting data');
                }
            });

        }
    }

    </script>

Controller for delete:

public function ajax_delete($id)
    {   
        $this->HomeModel->delete_by_id($id);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }

Model for delete:

public function delete_by_id($id)
    { 
      $this->db->where('case_main.id',$id);
      $this->db->delete('case_tracker.case_main');
      $this->db->where('case_overview.id',$id);
      $this->db->delete('case_tracker.case_overview'); 

    }
```

Note:- case_tracker is my schema name (im using postgre sql) and case_main and case_overview are my table name

All i want is that when i click on delete button that id row should be disabled by changing boolean value from false to true using codeigniter function or jquery.

Please help to processed with code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your function `ajax_delete`

Comment: @shibon i have added controller and model for delete.

Comment: Instead of delete you need to do update operation in query

Comment: $this->db->update('case_tracker.case_main',array('deleteflag'=>$delete_flag),array('id'=>$row['id']));  is this code proper ? should i use this line instead of delete in modal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved  my error..

Thnx @Shibon for finding  my silly (yet a big) mistake.

Changed my model to:

```
public function delete_by_id($id)
    { 
      $this->db->update('table_name',array('deleteflag' => '1'),array('id'=>$id));
       if ($this->db->affected_rows())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

note:- deleteflag is column name which is used as boolean true or false. (true for disable the row and false for none)